# How do I not show the processes that I can't kill with 'kill + [pid number]' command?

Tags: bash, shell, ps

I was working on a project "make a task manager in linux" at school
I used `ps -u [username] -o stat,cmd --sort=-pid | awk '{print $2$3$4}'` command to get cmd names from the ps command
If I use this command, I see the part of the result like this :

```
awk{print$2$3$4}
ps-u[username]
```

when I try to terminate those process using the pid of each process, it won't terminate them because their PID doesn't exist.

How could I not show those `awk{print$2$3$4}` and `ps-u[username]` ???

I couldn't think of any idea

```
ps -u [username] -o stat,cmd --sort=-pid | awk '{print $2$3$4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't kill them because they were only alive while the commands were running, which was the same command you used to generate that output.

There's a few ways you can suppress these. I think the easiest would be to filter them out in your awk script.:

```
ps -u [username] -o stat,cmd --sort=-pid | awk '$2!="awk" && $2!="ps"{print $2$3$4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

JNevill's solution excludes every running `awk` or `ps` process. I think it's better to exclude processes on `tty`. Also, you aren't getting complete commands with how you use `awk`. I (kind of) solved it using `sed`.

```
$ ps -u $USER -o stat,tty,cmd --sort=-pid | grep -v `ps -h -o tty $$` | sed -r  's/.*  (.*)$/\1/'
```

You can test it with the following command. I opened `man ps` in another terminal.

```
$ ps -u $USER -o stat,tty,cmd --sort=-pid | grep -v `ps -h -o tty $$` | grep -E '(ps|grep)'
S+   pts/14   man ps
```

The downside is, besides excluding `ps` and `grep`, it excludes your application as well.

Comment: may I ask what `ps hotty $$` means?

Comment: I've updated my question. Just `hotty` isn't very descriptive, they are short for the options `-h -o tty`. Why do you want to get rid of `pts/6`? The `pts` changes every time you open i.e. a terminal. Yesterday I had `pts/14`, today it's `pts/2`.